# Get correct device width in Xamarin forms

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm using [Xamarin labs in my Xamarin Forms](https://github.com/XLabs/Xamarin-Forms-Labs) project and it has a class that you can use to request information about the running device the app is on.

In my case I want to know the current Width of the Device screen.
To get this you need to wire up the `IDisplay` interface in the iOS appdelegate so that you can use that in your forms code.

So in my forms code I get the width by requesting `Resolver.Resolve<IDevice>.Display.Width` or `Resolver.Resolve<IDevice>.Display.XDpi`

Now when running this on a iPhone 6 simulator I'm getting 750 for width and 326 for XDpi.
What I'm now trying to do is use one of these 2 values to size images on the screen, so that they will have the exact width of the screen.

```
var image = new Image (){ Source = "img1.jpg", WidthRequest = _display.Width });
```

I'm displaying them inside a `ExtendedScrollView`

```
<StackLayout>
    <controlsXLabs:ExtendedScrollView x:Name="ImageScrollView"
                                      Orientation="Horizontal"
                                      AnimateScroll="true"
                                      Scrolled="OnScrolled">
        <StackLayout x:Name="DiscoverImagesStackLayout" Orientation="Horizontal" />
    </controlsXLabs:ExtendedScrollView>
    <Button Text="Click me" Clicked="OnButtonClicked" />
</StackLayout>
```

But the problem I'm facing now is that using Width ( 750 ) is to big ( retina scaling? ) and using XDpi is to small!

In other words how do I get the actual screen width that I can use to match with the width of my images?
Or am I doing something wrong?

Added screenshots, first one is to big, second to small ( in reference to the screen size )

[image: Display.Width ( to big )]

[image: Display.XDpi ( to small )]

Comment: have a look at [How to get Device Width/Height?](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/18679/how-to-get-device-width-height) or more specifically the [Device of XLabs](https://github.com/XLabs/Xamarin-Forms-Labs/wiki/Device)

Comment: Well @Rohit that post explains the same thing I'm explaining in my question. In other words, using the IDevice.Display property to retrieve the actual values. That part works. My question is, why are my images not shown correclty when I use that information to change the width of those images...

Comment: That is because its a [Xamarin.Forms WidthRequest](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29840923/1155650) and not constraint. You might have to create a custom image renderer and overide the [OnSizeRequest](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/member/Xamarin.Forms.Image.OnSizeRequest(System.Double,System.Double)/)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like Xamarin Forms XAML layout uses iOS's points for measuring - that is, a virtual resolution that is then scaled up to match the device's physical pixels.

However, the Xamarin Forms Labs `IDisplay` interface you are using returns the width/height value is physical pixels, and that's why everything looks so big. Luckily it seems to have a `Scale` property, which is the multiplier applied to the virtual resolution when the raster process wants to compose the final, physical image.

So, just divide `Display.Width` or `Display.Height` by `Display.Scale` and you will get the dimensions that the device's composition layer is using for the viewport size - in your case it should be a width of 375 points/virtual units since the iPhone 6 scale multiplier is 2.

If you want more information on how the virtual resolutions of iOS are corresponded with physical screen sizes, you can find a very detailed schematic in [this link](http://www.paintcodeapp.com/news/iphone-6-screens-demystified).