# Xamarin.Forms: Make image width proportional

Tags: image, xaml, layout, xamarin.forms

I want to use an image, which should have a width of 1/3 in regard of the parent width. The height of the image should scale with the width in the correct aspect ration. Thereby I want to control the padding on top/bottom of the image.

Of course I could use `WidthRequest`, but that are [some kind of fixed values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29808498/xamarin-forms-widthrequest-value-meaning).

```
<Image x:Name="logo"
       Source="logo.png"
       Aspect="AspectFit"
       HorizontalOptions="Center">
  <Image.WidthRequest>
    <OnIdiom x:TypeArguments="x:Double" Phone="150" Tablet="200" />
  </Image.WidthRequest>
</Image>
```

I could use `AbsoluteLayout` or `RelativeLayout`, but I don't know which height I should use. That is because I want to set a width and the height should correctly scale with it. Example:

```
<AbsoluteLayout>
  <Image x:Name="logo"
       Source="Assets/logo.png"
       Aspect="AspectFit"
       AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0.5,0.5,0.5,1"
       AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All" />
</AbsoluteLayout>
```

This works, but I can't specify the bottom padding exactly. On one platform it is ok, on another it's not. Now I tried `Grid`:

```
<Grid>
  <Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <RowDefinition Height="40" />
  </Grid.RowDefinitions>
  <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
  </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
  <Image x:Name="logo"
       HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
       Aspect="AspectFit"
       Grid.Row="0"
       Grid.Column="1">
    <Image.Source>
      <OnPlatform x:TypeArguments="ImageSource">
        <OnPlatform.iOS>logo.png</OnPlatform.iOS>
        <OnPlatform.Android>logo.png</OnPlatform.Android>
        <OnPlatform.WinPhone>Assets/logo.png.</OnPlatform.WinPhone>
      </OnPlatform>
    </Image.Source>
  </Image>
</Grid>
```

Here I also can't define the top & bottom padding. In portrait it is OK, in landscape not.

Any suggestions?