# What size does WidthRequest mean?

Tags: xamarin.forms

In Xamarin.Forms what unit of measurement is intrinsically associated with the number 100 like in this example:

```
<Button WidthRequest="100" />
```

1. Pixels
2. Points
3. Inches
4. None, the size depends on the the runtime platform

I already saw this question:
[Xamarin.Forms WidthRequest value meaning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29808498/xamarin-forms-widthrequest-value-meaning)

But while the answer explains HOW things work, it doesn't give an exact answer to my question.

For example, I am not sure if the correct answer is "Points" or "Size depends on the runtime platform". To me both are related because, the units you specify in Xamarin Forms are device independent units (can we call it points?) and they are translated to pixels by the platform.

In the same, if you think how device independent pixels work on iOS and Android, they are actually associated with the inch:

1 iOS point ~= 1/163 inch

1 Android dp/dip (density-independent pixel) ~= 1/160 inch

So while I understand how things work, I still don't know the correct answer to the question

Comment: thanks, I saw that question. I'd prefer to have an answer to be sure I got it right. The question explains HOW things work, but it doesn't give a clear definitive answer

Comment: please see my edit

Comment: In summary, a Xamarin.Forms programmer targeting phones and tablets can assume that all units of measurement are based on the following criterion: 160 units to the inch, equivalent to; 64 units to the centimeter. For more details, you could check the link below. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/creating-mobile-apps-xamarin-forms/summaries/chapter05

Comment: @WendyZang-MSFT Thanks but I already know about that, I already had mentioned all that in my question.

Comment: This is the default seetings of the WidthRequest. It needs to check the source code.