# How to bind a simple Label inside ListView for Xamarin Forms?

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.forms, xamarin-forms-4

> How a very simple binding would work for Label inside ListView?

I seem to have spent hours on this but can't figure out.

What is wrong with data binding of label?

Because three rows are displayed that means Observable collection from `View Model` has been bound.

> Am I over using x:DataType is it really needed for simple grid
> binding?

[image]

**XAML file**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage
    x:Class="Poc.ListViewGrouping.Views.LvDemo"
    xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Poc.ListViewGrouping.ViewModels"
    xmlns:model="clr-namespace:Poc.ListViewGrouping.Models">
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <StackLayout>
            <Label
                HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                Text="Welcome to Abhijeet's Page Of List View!"
                VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" />
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
    <ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
        <ToolbarItem Command="{Binding AddItemCommand}" Text="Add Milestone" />
    </ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
    <RefreshView x:DataType="local:Lv1Vm">
        <StackLayout BackgroundColor="Orange">
            <ListView
                x:Name="lv1"
                BackgroundColor="Green"
                ItemsSource="{Binding DS}">
                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate x:DataType="local:Lv1Vm">
                        <ViewCell>
                            <Frame BackgroundColor="Navy">
                                <StackLayout
                                    Padding="10"
                                    x:DataType="model:LvModel"
                                    BackgroundColor="Yellow"
                                    HeightRequest="30">
                                    <!--  Does not bind at all  -->
                                    <Label BackgroundColor="Red"
                                           Text="{Binding Name}" />
                                </StackLayout>
                            </Frame>
                        </ViewCell>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            </ListView>
        </StackLayout>
    </RefreshView>
</ContentPage>
```

**Code Behind File**

```
using Poc.ListViewGrouping.ViewModels;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Markup;
using Xamarin.Forms.Xaml;
namespace Poc.ListViewGrouping.Views
{
    [XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
    public partial class LvDemo : ContentPage
    {
        public Lv1Vm _viewModel;

        public LvDemo()
        {
            BindingContext = _viewModel = new Lv1Vm();

            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

**View Model**

```
using Poc.ListViewGrouping.Models;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Text;

namespace Poc.ListViewGrouping.ViewModels
{
    public class Lv1Vm : BaseViewModel
    {
        public ObservableCollection<LvModel> DS => new ObservableCollection<LvModel>()
        {
            new LvModel{Id = 1, Name = "Hello" },
            new LvModel{Id = 2, Name="Hi"},
            new LvModel{Id = 3, Name="Good Going"},
        };

        public Lv1Vm()
        {
            Title = "Lv1";
        }
    }
}
```

**Model**

```
public class LvModel
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Id { get; set; }

}
```

Comment: is `Name` a **public property** on `LvModel`?

Comment: @Jason yes added Model as well above.

Comment: `DS` is not a public property. Change it to be `public ObservableCollection<LvModel> DS { get => ew ObservableCollection<LvModel>()
{ new LvModel{Id = 1, Name = "Hello" }, new LvModel{Id = 2, Name="Hi"}, new LvModel{Id = 3, Name="Good Going"},};`

Comment: @GeraldVersluis, thanks but DS is indeed a public property already, I used expression body syntax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In fact, your binding is correct, and the reason it doesn't show up is because of all rows in a ListView have the same height by default.It doesn't compute the height of your child item anymore.

You could try to set `HasUnevenRows="True"`

```
<ListView
            HasUnevenRows="True"
            x:Name="lv1"
            BackgroundColor="Green"
            ItemsSource="{Binding DS}">
       <ListView.ItemTemplate>
              <DataTemplate x:DataType="local:Lv1Vm">
                  <ViewCell>
                      <Frame BackgroundColor="Navy">
                          <StackLayout
                                Padding="10"
                                x:DataType="model:LvModel"
                                BackgroundColor="Yellow"
                                HeightRequest="30">
                                <!--  Does not bind at all  -->
                              <Label BackgroundColor="Red"
                                       Text="{Binding Name}" />
                          </StackLayout>
                      </Frame>
                  </ViewCell>
            </DataTemplate>
      </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

or set `RowHeight`

```
<ListView
            HasUnevenRows="False"
            RowHeight="80"
            x:Name="lv1"
            BackgroundColor="Green"
            ItemsSource="{Binding DS}">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate x:DataType="local:Lv1Vm">
                    <ViewCell>
                        <Frame BackgroundColor="Navy">
                            <StackLayout
                                Padding="10"
                                x:DataType="model:LvModel"
                                BackgroundColor="Yellow"
                                HeightRequest="30">
                                <!--  Does not bind at all  -->
                                <Label BackgroundColor="Red"
                                       Text="{Binding Name}" />
                            </StackLayout>
                        </Frame>
                    </ViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

Answer (score 0):

I've never ran into this problem with a `StackLayout`, but I have with a `BoxView`. The `HeightRequest` on the container looks too small. According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29840923/1007881), Android is 64 units to the centimeter which would make that container around half a centimeter. Try changing the HeightRequest value.