# how to transform a pixel to xamarin.forms units?

Tags: xamarin.forms

1. there are 160 units per inch.
   2.If I created an **Photoshop** file that are 72 **dpi** then there will be 72 points per inch.
   3.If the element is `88px` height in **Photoshop** then what I have to set it in `xamarin`?

If the phone is 360dpi then the height in xamarin should be :`88 / 72 * 160 / 2`?
but it is not right.

Comment: where do you get /2 from?  88 / 72 * 160 = 196 pixels

Comment: 196 should be units? I want to get units in Xamarin by pixels from Photoshop

Comment: @Jason I just want to get units in Xamarin by pixels from Photoshop.

Comment: @maui Maybe this is helpful for you to understand the units in Xamarin Forms.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29808498/xamarin-forms-widthrequest-value-meaning

Comment: @JuniorJiang-MSFT I know the units in each platfform and I only want to know how to get units from pixels

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I know the units in each platfform and I only want to know how to get units from pixels

You could use [Xamarin.Essentials](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/device-display?context=xamarin%2Fxamarin-forms&tabs=android) to get the `Screen density` as follows:

```
// Get Metrics
var mainDisplayInfo = DeviceDisplay.MainDisplayInfo;
// Screen density
var density = mainDisplayInfo.Density;
```

If the density is `3` in iOS device and pixels is `88` , then there are `88/3` units in iOS.

> If the phone is 360dpi

That means it shoule be a Android device, and screen density also can be calculated by `360/160 = 2.25`. Then there are 88/2.25 units to set for `HeightRequest`.

================================Update==============================

If there is a `BoxView` in **Xaml** as follows:

```
<BoxView x:Name="MyBoxView" BackgroundColor="CadetBlue" HorizontalOptions="Fill"/>
```

And the effect:

[image]

Now I will print the `MyBoxView.Width`. the result is:

```
Console.WriteLine("++++MyBoxView++++" + MyBoxView.Width);

++++MyBoxView++++411.428571428571
```

If you use `var density = mainDisplayInfo.Density;` to get density, you will get `Screen Density::2.625`. (My device is *Piexl_2_pie_9_0* api 28 emulator)

You know the size of screen width is `1080` pixels, however the width is `411.428571428571`. That should means units of `WidthRequest`.

And if you put `411.428571428571 * 2.625` , you will get `1080` pixels.

Comment: no it not right. I mean If I have a photoshop design and all in it is pixel and how to get units from it? for example the button is 88px height. how to set the heightrequest in xamarin?

Comment: @maui  What do you mean "how to get units from it"? If it is pixel, you can get piexl from it.

Comment: @maui I have updated the answer, you can have a look when you have time.

Comment: I mean  If the boxView is 88px then I should set it's widthRequest according to different device?in different device android or ios one unit is not the same?

Comment: But as I know in one inch there are 160 units.and In one inch there are 72 pixels right? in 72dpi? so it means 1units = 160 /72?

Comment: @maui Okey, one inch there are 160 units that means **160dpi** . It's the units of device screen. You don't care about this. If the BoxView is 88px, you need to calculate the units on runtime by using `Pixels/ScreenDensity`.

Comment: @maui However, we can calculate the `ScreenDensity` by the `dpi` of device screen as my answer shared. Such as: `Actual-DPI/160`. I'm not sure whether it works for iOS/UWP device, but it works for Android device. Here `DPI` is not the best important. Because we can use **Xamarin.Essentials** to get the `ScreenDensity` directly.

Comment: If so I have to calculate it in every different device but it is not the Xamarin units. unit is to separate it from calculation in different device.you can use units in all device right?you do not need to care the dpi or others just use units is ok?

Comment: @maui Generally, we only set a default `HeightRequest` with a specified units value. It will be converted to diferent pixels in different devices. If you not minding this effect, you can use this. Else if you want to every device seems to be the same effect, we can call that show proportionally. Then you need to calcualte the units on runtime. It depends on you. In addition, the units of  `HeightRequest` is designed by Xamarin Forms, we can not modify it. When you setting `HeightRequest` for `BoxView`, it also use the units not the pixels.

Comment: But If I want to Set HeightRequest for BoxView,how many units I should set? in design it is 88 pixels in 72dpi. HeightReuqust = ?

Comment: @maui If so, use *72/160* is the `ScreenDensity`, and the units should be `88/ScreenDensity`. But you should know that the UI design of mobile application should follow the rationality of the mobile interface. If you follow other design of platform to convert it, it will not show properly. Usually we design the UI of the mobile application first, and then determine what kind of pixel image to use.

Comment: last question is all android width 480 units?

Comment: @maui If you mean the `480 units` is `480 dpi`, because this units is for screen of device. The answer is **No**, the almost of the recent published android phones is `480dpi`, the older android phone may have other dpis,such as `360dpi/240dpi`,etc.

Comment: @maui You could have a look at [android document](https://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screendensities) to research it. And here is [a helpful disscussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2025282/what-is-the-difference-between-px-dip-dp-and-sp) for it in SO.