# how to fix resolution in application?

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.forms

I wanted to know how the application can be displayed one size on all devices?

Because when I test my app on small devices, all the elements are either too big or do not fit on the screen.

What should be done to solve this problem?

I used `StackLayout` to arrange the elements.

This is one of my codes:

```
<StackLayout Orientation="Vertical"  Margin="10" Padding="10" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">


        <Label Text="WellCome to App" TextColor="Aquamarine" FontSize="40" FontAttributes="Bold,Italic"
           HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"/>


        <Label Text="Please select the topic you want:" FontSize="21" FontAttributes="Bold,Italic"
               HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" TextColor="DarkRed"/>


        <Grid  ColumnSpacing="0" RowSpacing="0" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="120"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="120"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="120"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="120"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="120"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="120"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>


            <Button Text="Space" TextColor="White" FontSize="Large"
                     BackgroundColor="Black"
                     HeightRequest="140"
                     WidthRequest="140"
                     CornerRadius="60"
                     HorizontalOptions="Center"
                     BorderWidth="1"
                     BorderColor="Silver"
                     Clicked="spaceButton_OnClicked">
                <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                    <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                        <VisualState x:Name="Normal">
                            <VisualState.Setters>
                                <Setter Property="Scale"
                                Value="1" />
                            </VisualState.Setters>
                        </VisualState>

                        <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                            <VisualState.Setters>
                                <Setter Property="Scale"
                                Value="0.8" />
                            </VisualState.Setters>
                        </VisualState>

                    </VisualStateGroup>
                </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
            </Button>


            <Button Text="Sports" FontSize="Large" Grid.Column="2"  
               TextColor="White" BackgroundColor="Black"
                 HeightRequest="140"
                 WidthRequest="140"
                 CornerRadius="60"
                 HorizontalOptions="Center"
                 BorderWidth="1"
                 BorderColor="Silver"
                 Clicked="sportButton_OnClicked">
                <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                    <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStatess">
                        <VisualState x:Name="Normal">
                            <VisualState.Setters>
                                <Setter Property="Scale"
                                Value="1" />
                            </VisualState.Setters>
                        </VisualState>

                        <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                            <VisualState.Setters>
                                <Setter Property="Scale"
                                Value="0.8" />
                            </VisualState.Setters>
                        </VisualState>

                    </VisualStateGroup>
                </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
            </Button>


            <Button Text="Game" FontSize="Large" Grid.Row="1"  Grid.Column="1"  
                TextColor="White" BackgroundColor="Black"
                 HeightRequest="140"
                 WidthRequest="140"
                 CornerRadius="60"
                 HorizontalOptions="Center"
                 BorderWidth="1"
                 BorderColor="Silver"
                 Clicked="gameButton_OnClicked">
                <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                    <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStatesss">
                        <VisualState x:Name="Normal">
                            <VisualState.Setters>
                                <Setter Property="Scale"
                                Value="1" />
                            </VisualState.Setters>
                        </VisualState>

                        <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                            <VisualState.Setters>
                                <Setter Property="Scale"
                                Value="0.8" />
                            </VisualState.Setters>
                        </VisualState>

                    </VisualStateGroup>
                </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
            </Button>


            <Button Text="Technology" FontSize="12" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" 
               TextColor="White" BackgroundColor="Black"
                 HeightRequest="140"
                 WidthRequest="140"
                 CornerRadius="60"
                 HorizontalOptions="Center"
                 BorderWidth="1"
                 BorderColor="Silver"
                 Clicked="techButton_OnClicked">
                <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                    <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStats">
                        <VisualState x:Name="Normal">
                            <VisualState.Setters>
                                <Setter Property="Scale"
                                Value="1" />
                            </VisualState.Setters>
                        </VisualState>

                        <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                            <VisualState.Setters>
                                <Setter Property="Scale"
                                Value="0.8" />
                            </VisualState.Setters>
                        </VisualState>

                    </VisualStateGroup>
                </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
            </Button>


            <Button  Text="History" FontSize="20" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="2" 
                TextColor="White" BackgroundColor="Black"
                 HeightRequest="140"
                 WidthRequest="140"
                 CornerRadius="60"
                 HorizontalOptions="Center"
                 BorderWidth="1"
                 BorderColor="Silver"
                 Clicked="oldButton_OnClicked">
                <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                    <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonSttes">
                        <VisualState x:Name="Normal">
                            <VisualState.Setters>
                                <Setter Property="Scale"
                                Value="1" />
                            </VisualState.Setters>
                        </VisualState>

                        <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                            <VisualState.Setters>
                                <Setter Property="Scale"
                                Value="0.8" />
                            </VisualState.Setters>
                        </VisualState>

                    </VisualStateGroup>
                </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
            </Button>
        </Grid
    </StackLayout>
```

My code is displayed in this form: [image]

Comment: Could you be more specific? Include some code, include some screenshot clarifying the problem

Comment: I added the photo and the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From shared code, the proportions of the elements are the same.Then you could set **Star**(`*`) for `Height` and `Width`, and set `HorizontalOptions` and `VerticalOptions` of `Button` be `FillAndExpand` to make the elements to fit all the sizes of device screen.

However, only setting this can not make the `Height` of **Grid** Item shows the same with Width:(**Pixel 2 Pie 9.0 420dpi**)

[image]

To solve this you could calcuate the `Width` and `Height` on runtime. From [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65083241/how-to-transform-a-pixel-to-xamarin-forms-units/65088159?noredirect=1#comment115124241_65088159), you will know if the units of `Width` and `Height` set a specified value, it will show different effects in different device.

Luckly, we can get Screen Density easily by using  [Xamarin.Essentials](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/device-display?context=xamarin%2Fxamarin-forms&tabs=android). If you need a 120 units value and based on **Pixel 2 Pie 9.0 420dpi (1080*1920)** android device, you can set `Height` or `Width` as follows:

```
// this device screen density is 2.625, therefore divide by 2.625, if you test in other device, you could divide by its screen density.
Row.Height/Width =  120 * (mainDisplayInfo.Density / 2.625)
```

Then it will show correctly:

[image]

The full **XML** Code as follows:

```
<StackLayout Orientation="Vertical"
                Margin="10"
                Padding="10"
                VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand">

    <Label Text="WellCome to App"
            TextColor="Aquamarine"
            FontSize="40"
            FontAttributes="Bold,Italic"
            HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
            VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" />


    <Label Text="Please select the topic you want:"
            FontSize="21"
            FontAttributes="Bold,Italic"
            HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
            VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
            TextColor="DarkRed" />


    <Grid  ColumnSpacing="0"
            RowSpacing="0"
            VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
            HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition x:Name="RowOne" Height="*" />
            <RowDefinition x:Name="RowTwo" Height="*" />
            <RowDefinition x:Name="RowThree" Height="*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition x:Name="ColumnOne" Width="*" />
            <ColumnDefinition x:Name="ColumnTwo" Width="*" />
            <ColumnDefinition x:Name="ColumnThree" Width="*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>


        <StackLayout HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
            <Button Text="Space"
                    TextColor="White"
                    FontSize="Large"
                    BackgroundColor="Black"
                    HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                    CornerRadius="60"
                    VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                    BorderWidth="1"
                    BorderColor="Silver">
                <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                    <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                        <VisualState x:Name="Normal">
                            <VisualState.Setters>
                                <Setter Property="Scale"
                                        Value="1" />
                            </VisualState.Setters>
                        </VisualState>

                        <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                            <VisualState.Setters>
                                <Setter Property="Scale"
                                        Value="0.8" />
                            </VisualState.Setters>
                        </VisualState>

                    </VisualStateGroup>
                </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
            </Button>
        </StackLayout>

        <Button Text="Sports"
                FontSize="Large"
                Grid.Column="2"
                TextColor="White"
                BackgroundColor="Black"
                VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                CornerRadius="60"
                HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                BorderWidth="1"
                BorderColor="Silver">
            <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStatess">
                    <VisualState x:Name="Normal">
                        <VisualState.Setters>
                            <Setter Property="Scale"
                                    Value="1" />
                        </VisualState.Setters>
                    </VisualState>

                    <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                        <VisualState.Setters>
                            <Setter Property="Scale"
                                    Value="0.8" />
                        </VisualState.Setters>
                    </VisualState>

                </VisualStateGroup>
            </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
        </Button>


        <Button Text="Game"
                FontSize="Large"
                Grid.Row="1"
                Grid.Column="1"
                TextColor="White"
                BackgroundColor="Black"
                VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                CornerRadius="60"
                HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                BorderWidth="1"
                BorderColor="Silver">
            <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStatesss">
                    <VisualState x:Name="Normal">
                        <VisualState.Setters>
                            <Setter Property="Scale"
                                    Value="1" />
                        </VisualState.Setters>
                    </VisualState>

                    <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                        <VisualState.Setters>
                            <Setter Property="Scale"
                                    Value="0.8" />
                        </VisualState.Setters>
                    </VisualState>

                </VisualStateGroup>
            </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
        </Button>


        <Button Text="Technology"
                FontSize="12"
                Grid.Row="2"
                Grid.Column="0"
                TextColor="White"
                BackgroundColor="Black"
                VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                CornerRadius="60"
                HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                BorderWidth="1"
                BorderColor="Silver">
            <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStats">
                    <VisualState x:Name="Normal">
                        <VisualState.Setters>
                            <Setter Property="Scale"
                                    Value="1" />
                        </VisualState.Setters>
                    </VisualState>

                    <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                        <VisualState.Setters>
                            <Setter Property="Scale"
                                    Value="0.8" />
                        </VisualState.Setters>
                    </VisualState>

                </VisualStateGroup>
            </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
        </Button>


        <Button  Text="History"
                    FontSize="20"
                    Grid.Row="2"
                    Grid.Column="2"
                    TextColor="White"
                    BackgroundColor="Black"
                    VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                    CornerRadius="60"
                    HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                    BorderWidth="1"
                    BorderColor="Silver">
            <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonSttes">
                    <VisualState x:Name="Normal">
                        <VisualState.Setters>
                            <Setter Property="Scale"
                                    Value="1" />
                        </VisualState.Setters>
                    </VisualState>

                    <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                        <VisualState.Setters>
                            <Setter Property="Scale"
                                    Value="0.8" />
                        </VisualState.Setters>
                    </VisualState>

                </VisualStateGroup>
            </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
        </Button>
    </Grid>
</StackLayout>
```

And the **ContentPage.cs**:

```
public partial class PageTestGrid : ContentPage
{
    public PageTestGrid()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        var mainDisplayInfo = DeviceDisplay.MainDisplayInfo;
        var density = mainDisplayInfo.Density;

        //if you want to set 120 as the Height of Grid
        RowOne.Height = 120 * (mainDisplayInfo.Density / 2.625);
        RowTwo.Height = 120 * (mainDisplayInfo.Density / 2.625);
        RowThree.Height = 120 * (mainDisplayInfo.Density / 2.625);

        ColumnOne.Width = 120 * (mainDisplayInfo.Density / 2.625);
        ColumnTwo.Width = 120 * (mainDisplayInfo.Density / 2.625);
        ColumnThree.Width = 120 * (mainDisplayInfo.Density / 2.625);

    }
}
```

The effect on **Phone H-dpi 4in Pie 9.0 H-dpi(480*800)**:

[image]