# xamarin forms use MainDisplayInfo.Density to calculate element width

Tags: xamarin.forms, screen-density

I want to set the width and height of an element to be approx 1cm. On UWP, I've determined empirically that setting the element's `WidthRequest` and `HeightRequest` to 25 comes pretty close.

Using `MainDisplayInfo.Density`, I would think that I should be able to compute the right value for various displays.

On my UWP display, the `Density` is 1. On my Android device, it's 3. So, shouldn't a value of 25 * 3 = 75 be correct ?

Unfortunately that isn't working. On my Android device, 75 is is displaying my element at about 2cm.

---

EDIT

Further, XF documentation [Units Of Measurement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/controls/common-properties), says that there are 64 device independent units per cm. According to that, shouldn't I be setting my desired width and height to 64 ? Not even close.

Comment: That's depending on devices. Different device has different density. See [this doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/creating-mobile-apps-xamarin-forms/summaries/chapter05#pixels-points-dps-dips-and-dius) may help.

Comment: Of course it does. But that's the whole point. Why is it not working for me ?

Comment: We usually don't use cm in different screen size. Will test and update here.

Comment: I don't understand your comment. I could use any units. The point is to have the controls be approximately the same size.

Comment: Well, I don't think the way you transform pixel to cm is correct. While I does not find a right way yet.

Comment: What do you think is correct ?

Comment: You can't mix Android with UWP. From this document, in iOS, it use points as units and that means 64 points = 1 cm. In Android, it use dps as units and that means 64 dps = 1cm. I don't know what units is UWP and you can't use 25 * 3 as 1 cm in Android. If the device Density, I wonder if it is 63/3? It looks like 1 cm in device.

Comment: I'm talking about the Xamarin platform independent units. According to the documentation, I should be able to use the same value on any platform and render something approximately the same size on all platforms.

Comment: No, I don't think so. Even if you use same Xamarin platform independent units, you will get different size after rendering to different platform/devices.

Comment: Then, what are platform independent units for ?

Comment: See [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29808498/xamarin-forms-widthrequest-value-meaning), it should be clear. Each platform should be different.